# Multiple views with tabs causing jumping between views - Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

So I have a Bottom Tabbed interface, with a listed Contact View. When you click on a contact it takes you too a Contact Details View for that contact.

Both Views have additional ion-tabs within them. The first Contact View works as expected, you can tab between "Friends", "Favorites", and "Requests". The problem happens when you enter the Contact Details View, clicking on any tab for that Contact will successfully switch tabs, but immediately take you back to the Contact View screen.

Here's a Plunker that shows what I mean:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Iuu1xgilMbGhmOeVkYKg?p=preview

For some reason in this Plunker it's defaulting to the Requests tab. So click Favorites, then Friends. 
Click on a Contact and then a Tab for that Contact. It will take you back to the first screen.

```
.state('tab.dash', {
  url: '/dash',
  views: {
    'tab-dash': {
      templateUrl: 'tab-dash.html',
      controller: 'DashCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('tab.friends', {
  url: '/friends',
  views: {
    'tab-friends': {
      templateUrl: 'tab-friends.html',
      controller: 'FriendsCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('tab.friend-detail', {
  url: '/friend/:friendId',
  views: {
    'tab-friends': {
      templateUrl: 'friend-detail.html',
      controller: 'FriendDetailCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I got around this was to have three buttons that replicated the tabs but changed view within the primary tab.